# How to make data entry to the sql table from the MS Access front end using Pass-through query?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

Im working with the application which uses MS Access as front end and Sql Server as back end. Im using ODBC connection to connect to Sql server and using a Passthrough query to populate a form in datasheet view. I want to add a new record to the datasheet which should also inserted into the table. How i can perform Insert in the datasheet view of the Form using Passthrough query

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Pass-through SELECT queries are by definition read-only.

A PT query sends an SQL string to the database server. If `ReturnsRecords` is True, it shows the returning result set, but it doesn't create an editable datasheet.

You must base your form on an Access query or directly on a linked ODBC table.

Edit: see also [How to make a passthrough / passthru query editable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18898032/3820271)