# MS Access + Postgres Accent / Case insensitive editable filter

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, filter, case-insensitive, accent-insensitive

I want to filter a form using accent and case insensitive filters.

MS Access doesn't support either, but Posgres does. Using these for reference:
[Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations)
[PostgreSQL: How to make "case-insensitive" query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005302/postgresql-how-to-make-case-insensitive-query)

I asked how to send Postgres specific SQL from within access and the solution is to use a passthrough query [Postgresql syntax in ms access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64330495/postgresql-syntax-in-ms-access)

And I get the results I want, regardless of accent or case. HOWEVER, the form's recordset is no longer editable. From my research (for example: [How to make a passthrough / passthru query editable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898032/how-to-make-a-passthrough-passthru-query-editable) ) Pass through queries are not editable/updateable

Is there a way to filter a form with accent/case insensitive filters and have the resulting recordset updateable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Access query (not Pass-Through), using the [StrComp Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/strcomp-function-a9a4531e-3b2a-4218-b139-f7442bc10b96) with `vbBinaryCompare` = 0.

```
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE StrComp(foo, "Aáà", 0) = 0
```

Result 0 = Exact match.